# best way to download multiiple small images

Tags: xml, image, download

I found another similar question: [Best way to download images from XML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002019/best-way-to-download-images-from-xml-content) in StackOverflow, but not exactly the same.

I have multiple small images from XML content and I have control over both server and client side. Shall I embed image bytes into XML or only pass urls for each image in XML and expect the client to initiate http calls again to download images? I am shooting for low latency but not a lot of images: 100 images of size 10-15k.

Any suggestion/comment is welcomed.

Comment: Embedding image bytes in XML will result in invalid XML.  (or very fat XML full of entities and risks of encoding issues)

Comment: i will encode the image binaries when embedded in xml. considering that, what will be the best solution?

Comment: That would make the XML six times bigger than the image.

Comment: depending on the encoding mechanism, it will be 30-40% more if I do it right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a single HTTP request and return a [multi-part MIME response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages).

Comment: do you mean the http request will return multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your XML will be used.

If only some of the images will be used, then putting URLs in the XML is the best solution.

If you expect the XML user will use all the images every time, then embedded the image into the XML is not a bad idea.

If it's me I would just put the URL into XML because that's more scalable solution, and probably more maintainable. One important "feature" of XML is it's humane readable; putting lots of binary data into the XML defeats that purpose.

Having URLs in the XML probably won't introduce huge latency issue as the client can use many 
techniques to reduce latency (like what SLaks suggested).